# Disable Read Only SharePoint Content Types - Powershell

Tags: powershell, content-type, pnp, pnp-powershell

I use the PnP Commandlets to do much of my site building but cannot figure out how to make Site Content Types not read-only. There is no way to do this with commandlets so I'm looking for some help.

I'd assume it was something along the line of:

```
$contentType = "Document Type"
$creds = Get-Credential
$url = [MY URL]
Connect-PnpOnline -Identity $url -Credentials $creds
$theContentType = Get-PnpContentType -Identity $contentType
```

This is where I get lost. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `### Make Content Types Not Read Only
$ctlist = Get-PnpContentType

foreach ($ctype in $ctList) { if ($ctype.Group -like "HM*") 
{ 
$ct = Get-PnpContentType $ctype
$ct.ReadOnly = $false
$ct.Update($true)
Execute-PnpQuery

}}`

Answer (score 0):

Got it.

```
### Make Content Types Not Read Only
$ct = Get-PnpContentType $ctype
$ct.ReadOnly = $false
$ct.Update($true)
Execute-PnpQuery

}}
```

Comment: You can accept your own answer. It'll prevent it from automatic bumping to homepage.